# 14.04 wifi has disappeared, only have wifi in house

Tags: wireless

The "enable wifi" option on my network connections has disappeared and as a result I've lost all internet connection. Enable networking is checked but it wants an ethernet connection. I can't do that.

```
lshw -class network shows

*-network UNCLAIMED 

description: Network controller

product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter

vendor: Qualcomm Atheros

physical id: 0

bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0

version: 01

width: 64 bits

clock: 33MHz

capabilities: bus_master cap_list

configuration: latency=0

resources: memory:f7c00000-f7c7ffff memory:f7c80000-f7c8ffff
```

This is strange. Wifi has been running this computer for several years and it suddenly disappeared after a shut down.

Comment: What is `rfkill list all`giving you?

Comment: It doesn't return anything

Comment: What about `dmesg | grep ath`? I assume atheros shows up as `ath0` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Forced update (without internet) and the updater managed to sort out the problem. I still don't know how the driver managed to become unattached (I'd lost sound, too) but things are working now.